# Changing colormap data matlab

Tags: matlab, image-scaling

I have a simple matrix that contains only the values -1000 -10 -1 0 1 10

I want to display it with imagesc and specify in the colormap separate colors for each value, how can this be obtained?

Answer (score 0):

imagesc(matrix);

Click in the top panel on "Insert Colorbar". A colorbar appears -> right click and click "open colormap editor" that works for me

otherwise (in code) define a map and set a color for every value

Comment: how do I set it to every specific value?

Comment: Here is a small exmaple u will understand: `v = [   255,   0,   0
          0,   0, 255   ]./255;    

Indices = [ 0
     20  ];

ColorMap = interp1(Indices./Indices(size(Indices,1)),v,linspace(0,1,Indices(size(Indices,1))));

I = linspace(0,1,Indices(size(Indices,1)));
figure;imagesc(I(ones(1,10),:)')
colormap(ColorMap)`